# No LoginModules configured error when LoginContext is created (JAAS)

Tags: java, osgi, kerberos, jaas

created a LoginContext object and passed a name, and with that entry I created a .conf file. I set the system property "java.security.auth.login.config" in the code, with relative/absolute paths to the conf file.  When the code is executed, I get the following error.

javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for Sample.

any clue why  the config is not getting picked up? Am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated.

Code for the above

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","sampleConfig.conf");
loginContext = new LoginContext("Sample", new CustomCallbackHandler());
loginContext.login();
```

sampleConfig.conf

```
Sample {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};
```

the file doesn't seem to be getting picked up. Even when I changed the file name/file path/ do any syntax changes in the conf file, I still see only the previous error.

please note that this is being done in a OSGI bundle.

Any help?

Comment: Please describe the environment where you are testing your code.  Are you using Equinox?  Are you testing on Windows (any version)?  Have you turned on any of the OSGI class loader debug switches?  Specifically these: `org.eclipse.osgi/debug=true` and `org.eclipse.osgi/debug/loader=true`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the concrete URL of the configuration file `sampleConfig.conf` via `org.osgi.framework.Bundle#getResource(String)`.

Insert this `URL` as value in `System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config",<URL>);`.

If your configuration file is a part of the OSGi-Framework use the Framework-Bundle (id: 0) otherwise use the bundle containing the configuration file.

**EDIT**

Maybe use a [Configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html) object instead of the configuration file.

See my answer at question: [In jaas can we use an object of javax.security.auth.login.Configuration class as an alternative to LoginModule configuration using .config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747711/in-jaas-can-we-use-an-object-of-javax-security-auth-login-configuration-class-as/30901782#30901782)

```
public LoginContext(String name,
                    Subject subject,
                    CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
                    Configuration config)
             throws LoginException
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sample {
  sample.module.SampleLoginModule required debug=true;
};
```

Then create your customCallBackHandler and LoginModule.