# In jaas can we use an object of javax.security.auth.login.Configuration class as an alternative to LoginModule configuration using .config files

Tags: java, security, jaas

While performing JAAS authentication I do not want to use a **.config** file for **LoginModule** lookup/configuration. My question is; is there a way to do this with out using a **.config** file? or can we use **javax.security.auth.login.Configuration** object for this purpose because it not clear to me after reading Oracle javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Pass your [Configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html) at constructor of [LoginContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/LoginContext.html).

See JavaDoc at [LoginContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/LoginContext.html):

> [...]
>
> 2. Configuration
>
>    If the constructor has a Configuration input parameter and the caller specifies a non-null Configuration, the LoginContext uses the caller-specified Configuration.
>
> [...]

```
public LoginContext(String name,
                    Subject subject,
                    CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
                    Configuration config)
             throws LoginException
```